# a simple MPI can't run after compile

Tags: runtime-error, mpi, hpc

i write a simple MPI program:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include "mpi.h"
  3 
  4 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
  5 {
  6         int rank;
  7         int size;
  8 
  9         MPI_Init(0,0);
 10         MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
 11         MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
 12         printf("Hello World from process %d of %d\n",rank,size);
 13         MPI_Finalize();
 14         return 0;
 15 }
```

the program compile successflly,but can't run

i use "mpirun -np 4 ./hello" or "mpirun -np 4 hello"

it shows like this:

```
_create_ep, create command failed: Operation not permitted
GLEX_ERR(ln0): _init_glex(608), _create_ep: system error
_create_ep, create command failed: Operation not permitted
GLEX_ERR(ln0): _init_glex(608), _create_ep: system error
_create_ep, create command failed: Operation not permitted
GLEX_ERR(ln0): _init_glex(608), _create_ep: system error
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(498)........: 
MPID_Init(187)...............: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89)...........: 
MPID_nem_init(320)...........: 
MPID_nem_glex_init(74).......: 
MPIDI_nem_glex_init_glex(610): Cannot create GLEX endpoint.
```

besides,i wirite this program on HPC.And I guess the problem "Cannot create GLEX endpoint" maybe related to the HPC(HPC has already deployed MPI).

Comment: Try `mpiexec -np 4 -f <machinefile> ./hello`. Where your  machine file contains the hostname and the number of processors on each host.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure of the level of support for `MPI_Init()` when null pointers are passed as arguments (I think there is something like calling it without arguments supported since MPI 3.0, but I wouldn't commit on that).
However, I would definitely replace `MPI_Init(0,0)` in your code by `MPI_Init( &argc, &argv )` for a starter.

EDIT: my bad, MPI_Init() is supposed to support null pointer as argument as stated [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node43.htm).
However, trying with `MPI_Init( &argc, &argv )` would still be my first try for fixing the issue.

Comment: OK, this looks like an environmental issue. Most probably, if this runs on a HPC cluster, you need to submit your job through a batch scheduler like PBS, SLURM, LSF, LoadLeveller... Without the batch environment, MPI_Init cannot initialise the MPI environment, hence the error message. Refer to your system administrator or local documentation for that.

Comment: thank you.I have solved this problems.  "yhrun -n 4 -p MIC mpitest".  this directive works.